# Angular 2 - Custom Validator Syntax

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

Please can somebody explain the following TypeScript syntax to me:

```
{[s: string]: boolean}
```

This is the return type for a `ValidatorFn` within Angular 2. Particularly, what does the array: `[s: string]` denote?

While writing my own custom `ValidatorFn` function, what is the purpose of the boolean field? There seems to be no difference in the following:

```
startsWithZero(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value.indexOf('0') !== 0) {
        return {'does not start with zero': true};
    }

    return null;
}
```

**vs.**

```
startsWithZero(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value.indexOf('0') !== 0) {
        return {'does not start with zero': false};
    }

    return null;
}
```

The Angular documentation is a little abstract in this regard and cannot find much on Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, the type annotation `{[s: string]: boolean}` means a dictionary where the key is a `string` and the value is a `boolean`.

Such types are referred to as [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). This a typical way of describing dictionaries (a.k.a. hash maps).

In Angular 2, the `ValidatorFn` is typed as:

```
export interface ValidatorFn {
    (c: AbstractControl): {
        [key: string]: any;
    };
}
```

...a function that takes an `AbstractControl` and returns a dictionary - the key identifies the validation rule, e.g. `maxLength`, and the value can be anything that explains why the rule failed, e.g. `{'requiredLength': maxLength, 'actualLength': v.length}`. It doesn't have to be a `boolean`.

Examples from Angular 2 source are [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/validators.ts#L56).

Answer (score 1):

I think its evaluating a string variable and assigning that variable a Boolean type;  like [s: string] = "myVar".  and then its actually saying "myVar: Boolean"